# how to run django app binded with gunicorn?

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to run a pre-built django project binded with gunicorn & nginx, following the tutorial publishded over this link.

[How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04)

The tree command on the project folder gives this output.

[image]

when I publish the project with `# python manage.py runserver`, I can view its contents. But when I try to bind it using unicorn with following command, it shows following errors.

```
# gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 DjangoWebsiteSample.eccomerceProject.wsgi.py 
[2019-05-10 05:25:11 +0000] [1912] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2019-05-10 05:25:11 +0000] [1912] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1912)
[2019-05-10 05:25:11 +0000] [1912] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-05-10 05:25:11 +0000] [1916] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1916
[2019-05-10 05:25:11 +0000] [1916] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 377, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named DjangoWebsiteSample.eccomerceProject.wsgi.py
[2019-05-10 05:25:11 +0000] [1916] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1916)
[2019-05-10 05:25:11 +0000] [1912] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-05-10 05:25:11 +0000] [1912] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this command:

**`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 eccomerceProject.wsgi`**

Comment: where I could see the django project name?